# OnFocusLost dropdown hides

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I'm using bootstrap and I try to put text fields inside dropdown menu context, but when I click in the fields, my dropdown get hide.

How can i click in text field and do not close my dropdown?

```
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Entrar <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Usuario">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Senha">
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Entrar</button>

                            </li>

                            <li><a href="#">Meu Perfil</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Meus Serviços - Minhas contratações</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sair</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it..

```
$('.dropdown-menu  input').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```